# How to get best match using java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Here is my use case. I have different file processing modules which is invoked based on the file name. So if the filename matches the pattern associated with a certain module that module will pick up the file.
I have a catch all pattern defined which is used to do default processing, but this pattern should only kick in if I haven't got a better match.

Consider the following scenario

```
Pattern 1 -    Sample_[0-9]*.xls  
Pattern 2 -    [a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]*.xls
```

Now given a file `"Sample_11"`, I want Pattern 1 to be applied as its a better match than Pattern 2, however the method  `java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher().matches()` just returns true or false.
Is there any way to identify what is the better match?

EDIT:
The patterns are defined outside the system (this is a weird use case), so I cannot order 
them as suggested by many. In a sense I am looking infer the results of matching to decide if that is the best match or not. Hope this clarifies my question.

Thanks,

Raam

Comment: Try first pattern 1 - if there are any matches then you know that you have a better match and you don't need to use Pattern 2.

Comment: Regular expressions define 'best' as 'longest'. Is that your definition?

Comment: Imagine a directed graph of patterns, where more specific patterns are children of less specific patterns. (If you can't, the question is meaningless). Apply patterns from most specific to least specific, such that you never apply a pattern unless all its children are applied.

Comment: The more explicit and restrictive is the best (in general)

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain of responsibility design pattern ([wiki here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)). Loop (or iterate down a list) through each regex `Pattern` from most specific to least specific until you find one that matches. Then do the appropriate processing for that match.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the Boolean not sufficient here?  Your logic should be checking a more specific regex (or list of regex) first, going down the code path tied to whatever specific regex matches. It should only go on to the catch all if it found no match for the specific patterns. I think the Boolean should work fine for you unless there is more to your problem that I don't see.

Imagine a Map where the key is the pattern and the value is a custom interface for handling a match (let's call it MatchHandler). Iterate the map and if a pattern matches, invoke that MatchHandler.  If no match, check the default pattern and if a match, invoke the default MatchHandler. If you needed ordered processing you could use a LinkedHashMap.

Now if you won't know the patterns before hand (and it sounds like that's the case for you) then things get a little more tricky. One possible answer would be to write another regex that evaluates the occurrences of general matching constructs in the pattern (things like [a-z], *, etc). Patterns with more occurrences of these general matching constructs will be less specific matches. It's not perfect but it could work for what you are doing.  Just be sure to do a lot of escaping in this other pattern due to the fact that it is looking for regex based constructs using regex itself.